# Axiom of choice in graph theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, solution-verification

I have produced the follwoing proof for the theorem that every connected graph has a spanning tree using Zorn's lemma.

> Let $G$ be the connected graph and consider the set of all tress denoted by $S$. This set $S$ under subgraph relation $\subset$ is a partially ordered set$(S,\subset)$. Any chain $C$ of the poset is a chain of tress with respect to inclusion relation. Then, the union of $A=\cup\ T_i$ where $T_i \in C$ $i \in \{1,2,3,....,n\}$  is the upper bound of the chain $C$.

> Suppose $A$ is not a tree. Then $A$ is either disconnected or there is cycle present. Suppose $A$ is disconnected then there are two vertices $x, y \in A$ such that there is no path between them. Let $x \in T_x$ and $y \in T_y$ and $T_x , T_y \in A.$ Since $T_x$ and $T_y$ is in chain $C$ (because $A$ is the upper bound of $C$) either $T_x \subset T_y$ or $T_y \subset T_x$ and in either cases $x$ must be connected to $y$ in the bigger tree. Hence, $x$ and $y$ is connected in $A$ which is a contradiction.

> Now suppose that there is a cycle $c \in A$. Every edge of $c$ must appear in some $T_i$ in $C$, i,e. $E(c) \subset E(T_i)$ which is a contradiction as $T_i$ is acyclic. Therefore, $A$ is a tree and the upper bound of chain $C$. Then, by Zorn's lemma
> there is a maximal element $T^{\ast}$ in $S$ as every chain of $S$ has an upper bound which is a tree.

> Suppose $T^{\ast}$ is not a spanning tree suggesting that there is some vertex $u \in G$ that is not in $T^{\ast}$. Adding the edges between some vertex in $T^{\ast}$ and $x$ creates a new tree $T^{\ast\ast}$ where $T^{\ast} \subset T^{\ast\ast}$ which is a contradiction on maximality of $T^{\ast}$.

I would greatly appreciate on any comments regarding any mistakes or missing parts of the proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/is-it-true-that-a-connected-graph-has-a-spanning-tree-if-the-graph-has-uncounta?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

It’s basically correct. I did notice one notational glitch in the proof that $A$ is acyclic: a cycle $c$ in $A$ is not an element of $A$, so it’s incorrect to write $c\in A$.

And you could stand to say a bit more in the last paragraph. If $T^*$ is not a spanning tree, there is at least one vertex $u$ in $G$ that is not in $T^*$. $G$ is connected, so there is a path in $G$ from $u$ to some vertex $v$ of $T^*$, say $u=w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_n=v$. Let $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be minimal such that $w_k$ is in $T^*$; then $w_{k-1}$ is not in $T^*$ and is adjacent to $w_k$, which **is** in $T^*$, so we can add the vertex $w_{k-1}$ and the edge $\{w_{k-1},w_k\}$ to $T^*$ to get a strictly larger tree, contradicting the maximality of $T^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Elise: You’re very welcome.